# Avoiding label indenting in C++

Tags: c++, vim, indentation

<sub>*I guess this was asked before, but I could not find any similar question.*</sub>

When writing part of the scope operator in C++, Vim guesses that it's going to be a label (on the first `:`) and then indents it automatically, which is pretty annoying. Example:

#1 - initial typing

```
{
    std
```

#2 - added `:`

```
{
std:
```

#3 - added `:`

```
{
    std::
```

Of course, it's correct at the end, but is there any way to disable the automatic indent for labels? I rarely use them, and it wouldn't be a great deal to indent manually in those cases.

Comment: First hit google: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_stop_auto_indenting

Comment: @AJG85 - I don't think, that the @sidyll want to stop the whole auto intending

Comment: @Kiril Kirov is right. I just want to disable the label indenting on cpp files. And I have some knowledge on syntax files, the problem is that apparently the C indenting is built-in, so I'd like some help on that. $VIMRUNTIME/indent/cpp.vim didn't help.

Comment: For those voting to close (I guess c++ tag viewers) please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25925/160504

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just tell vim not to de-indent labels with:

```
:set cinoptions+=L0
```

For reference, if by "visibility" modifiers you mean access specifiers, these can be set to not indent with:

```
:set cinoptions+=g0
```