# Setting to skip over punctuation when moving forwards and backwards words

Tags: vim

When I'm using vim I generally never want to move to a punctuation mark when I press **w** or **b** to go forwards or backwards. So I'm wondering if there's a setting or something to change this functionality?

e.g. If I've got some code like

> object.method(args)

and my cursor is at the [o] in "object" then I want **w** to move to the [m] in "method", and another **w** to move to the [a] in "args". I don't want it to land on the [.] or the [(]. If I've ever wanted to move to a punctuation char I've always used **f** or **F** to jump straight to it. I've never personally wanted to move to a punctuation char when I move through words and I just realized this is really bugging me.

Comment: I don't know if there is a better solution, but if you don't mind changing the contents of `@/` you can always type `/\<\w`. Or create a map to that if you use it often.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/225266/469210

Comment: @Sidyll: yes of course! I didn't read the question carefully. I now see that the OP wants to move to `[m]` and not just skip the `[.]`. I deleted my answer for now. I'm replying here because I'm not sure if my reply on the deleted answer will reach you.

Comment: @yoda, well this one reached! Back to the question, I can't imagine another way (other than `/`). Maybe, if losing the contents of `@/` is an issue, it could be saved to another register, but I wonder if that's not going to be a rather expensive operation. Anyway, I hope Vim gets multiple search registers soon. It's just a matter of finding another free character to use :-)

Comment: @yoda: another idea just occurred to me. What if there was a command like `_/` to search but not to include the pattern in the `@/` register? Hmm, if Vim lacks that, it's certainly something interesting to investigate and create a possible patch.

Comment: @sidyll: I like your solution to move with `/\<\w`, but one annoyance is that it highlights all the words it will move to when you have highlighting turned on.

Comment: @yoda I agree. A way to search without storing the search or triggering
highlighting is certainly something to look into with care. Regarding this
question, I think the little function I posted should work.

Comment: @borrible: changing iskeyword won't resolve the question unfortunately. That can only make w act like W.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too find that I would like a movement that is more inclusive that `w`, but not as inclusive as `W`. In particular, I would like a movement that only considers tokens beginning with alphanumeric characters as significant.

So I came up with the following:

```
" <SPACE>   : forward to next word beginning with alphanumeric char
" <S-SPACE> : backward to prev word beginning with alphanumeric char
" <C-SPACE> : same as above (as <S-SPACE> not available in console Vim
" <BS>      : back to prev word ending with alphanumeric char
function! <SID>GotoPattern(pattern, dir) range
    let g:_saved_search_reg = @/
    let l:flags = "We"
    if a:dir == "b"
        let l:flags .= "b"
    endif
    for i in range(v:count1)
        call search(a:pattern, l:flags)
    endfor
    let @/ = g:_saved_search_reg
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <SPACE> :<C-U>call <SID>GotoPattern('\(^\\|\<\)[A-Za-z0-9_]', 'f')<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <SPACE> :<C-U>let g:_saved_search_reg=@/<CR>gv/\(^\\|\<\)[A-Za-z0-9_]<CR>:<C-U>let @/=g:_saved_search_reg<CR>gv
nnoremap <silent> <S-SPACE> :<C-U>call <SID>GotoPattern('\(^\\|\<\)[A-Za-z0-9_]', 'b')<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <S-SPACE> :<C-U>let g:_saved_search_reg=@/<CR>gv?\(^\\|\<\)[A-Za-z0-9_]<CR>:<C-U>let @/=g:_saved_search_reg<CR>gv
nnoremap <silent> <BS> :call <SID>GotoPattern('[A-Za-z0-9_]\(\>\\|$\)', 'b')<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <BS> :<C-U>let g:_saved_search_reg=@/<CR>gv?[A-Za-z0-9_]\(\>\\|$\)<CR>:<C-U>let @/=g:_saved_search_reg<CR>gv

" Redundant mapping of <C-SPACE> to <S-SPACE> so that
" above mappings are available in console Vim.
"noremap <C-@> <C-B>
if has("gui_running")
    map <silent> <C-Space> <S-SPACE>
else
    if has("unix")
        map <Nul> <S-SPACE>
    else
        map <C-@> <S-SPACE>
    endif
endif
```

I have had this for a long time now, and I find that I use `<SPACE>`/`<C-SPACE>` movements *so* much more than `w` and `W`; it just seems more useful when coding. You can, of course, map the commands to whatever keys you find useful or more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @Jeet. That works great in a small test. I was wondering if you could write an extra mapping that works like 'e' to jump to the end of words, but only considering alphanumerics.

Comment: @Tub: how would that mapping behave differently from `<SPACE>e` ?

Answer (score 2):

Even running the risk of creating a script for something that's built-in ([like
I did last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471556/avoiding-label-indenting-in-c/6471790#6471790)), here is a little function that may help accomplishing
this.

```
function! JumpToNextWord()
    normal w
    while strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) !~ '\w'
        normal w
    endwhile
endfunction
```

Basically, what it does is executing the standard <kbd>w</kbd> and repeating it
if the character under the cursor is not in a word character (feel free to
change that pattern.

If you add that and a little map in your *.vimrc*:

```
nnoremap <silent> ,w :call JumpToNextWord()<CR>
```

It should work.

Comment: @Sidyll: Link directly to your previous answer, as people won't have to search for it. You'll also get upvotes if it's easier for them to find :)

Comment: Thanks @yoda, I updated it to match the answer and not the question. That answer was a shame, but I decided to keep it there :-)

Comment: Hi sidyll, I like this solution. I wonder if you could get it to work in visual mode (so visual selections can be expanded).

Comment: Thanks @Jeet . Your solution is far more advanced and interesting too. Regarding visual mode, well, that's more complicated :-) I have no idea.

Comment: @sidyll: simpler is always better if it does the job! Which is why I like your solution. But, unfortunately, support for visual mode is pretty important for any movement if it is to be part of the Vim ecosystem. I'll see if I can get your approach to work in visual mode.

Comment: Thanks @Jeet, and yes, visual mode is important too. Ok, if you came up with a solution, add it to your answer!

Comment: I like this solution. However, there is an infinite loop if the buffer is empty. So you have to be careful :)