# vim stop indentation of colon inside comments in c++

Tags: vim, comments, auto-indent

How can I stop indentation changes for a colon in c++ source code with vim?

Example:

```
class X
{
    public:
        /*
           Some comment here
TODO: make it better...
*/
        void f() {}
};
```

Should be:

```
class X
{
    public:
        /*
           Some comment here
           TODO: make it better...
           */
        void f() {}
};
```

Comment: The following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471556/avoiding-label-indenting-in-c stops label indentation but not only inside comments.